# Can Yahoo Answers API be used to write data

Tags: api, yahoo

The 'My Projects' page on Yahoo Developer network gives the following three options for Yahoo Answers permissions:

1. None
2. **Read/Write** With your user's permission, you can access their
   Yahoo! Answers private data and **post content** ( eg: questions,
   answers, ratings) on their behalf.
3. Read With your user's permission,
       you can read their Yahoo! Answers personal data.

But the documentation of the API http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/ doesn't have any methods which allow an application to post questions and answers on the behalf of the user. Have I missed out something or is that the way it is?